# canonical form of parabolic-type PDE involving $\exp(x)$ and $\ln(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The attached picture skips a lot of the work, but I've worked this problem at least 6 times in the last 8 hours, still getting stuck at reducing to canonical form - that is, trying to solve for $x$ and $y$ within the system of equations. I cannot determine how to solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\xi$ and $\eta$. Is there some trick I'm not seeing or some better choice of $\eta$? The equation is supposed to be solvable.

[image: Nearly canonical form]

Comment: Have you tried $\eta(x,y) = y$? This should get rid of coordinate-dependent coefficients in front of $u_{\eta\eta}$ and $u_\eta$.